# Jenkins throwing null pointer error while parsing change log

Tags: java, android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have just started with jenkins and I am getting null pointer error while parsing change log. I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

I am posting the error log

```
Started by user Neeraj Kumar
Building in workspace C:\Bitnami\jenkins-1.641-0\apps\jenkins\jenkins_home\workspace\Test_Jenkins<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10<br>
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/kumar1773/Test_Jenkins.git # timeout=10<br>
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/kumar1773/Test_Jenkins.git<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git --version # timeout=10<br>
using .gitcredentials to set credentials<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git config --local credential.username Kumar1773@gmail.com # timeout=10<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Bitnami\JENKIN~1.641\APACHE~1\temp\git5284765403770747351.credentials\" # timeout=10<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/kumar1773/Test_Jenkins.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10<br>
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD<br>
Seen branch in repository origin/master<br>
Seen branch in repository origin/phase1<br>
Seen 3 remote branches<br>
Checking out Revision 3e5b8d59a7c8d0c92073439572042e8b0e8f7b26 (origin/phase1)<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git checkout -f<br> 3e5b8d59a7c8d0c92073439572042e8b0e8f7b26<br>
 > C:/Bitnami/jenkins-1.641-0/git/bin/git rev-list 3e5b8d59a7c8d0c92073439572042e8b0e8f7b26 # timeout=10<br>
java.io.IOException: Failed to parse changelog<br>
    at<br> hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:625)<br>
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)<br>
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)<br>
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)<br>
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)<br>
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)<br>
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)<br>
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:187)<br>
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.metadata.scm.SourceMetadata.<init>(SourceMetadata.java:61)<br>
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.metadata.scm.SourceMetadataExtractor$FromGitBuildActions.getSourceMetadata(SourceMetadataExtractor.java:242)<br>
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.metadata.scm.SourceMetadataExtractor$FromBuildActions.extract(SourceMetadataExtractor.java:139)<br>
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.metadata.scm.SourceMetadataExtractor.extract(SourceMetadataExtractor.java:101)<br>
    at com.google.jenkins.plugins.metadata.scm.SourceMetadataBuildListener.onChangeLogParsed(SourceMetadataBuildListener.java:50)<br>
    at hudson.model.listeners.SCMListener.onChangeLogParsed(SCMListener.java:120)<br>
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:623)<br>
    ... 6 more
Finished: FAILURE<br>
```